# Exception in conversion of date formats

Tags: java

I am trying to convert the date format from "dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy" to "MM/dd/yyyy"

```
String inputPattern = "dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy";
    String outputPattern = "MM/dd/yyyy";
    SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(inputPattern);
    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(outputPattern);

    Date date=inputFormat.parse("Tue Dec 07 15:59:03 IST 2010");
    System.out.println("Date : "+outputFormat.format(date));
```

But While running the above code the following exception occurs

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'o'
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.compile(SimpleDateFormat.java:769)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initialize(SimpleDateFormat.java:576)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:501)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:476)
at com.kpub.web.bean.action.ReportGeneration.main(ReportGeneration.java:198)
```

What may be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use for input pattern as;

```
EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy
```

[From Java Manual](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)